# Chi Square Test in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, chi-squared, write.table

I have a dataset on Excel which has lots of columns (A, B, C...Z) and I want to perform a Chi-Square Test to obtain p value between B e C column only. Columns B and C only have two types of values: 0, 1. The column A on Excel corresponds to the identification number of the person.
I proceeded as follows:

1. I created a contingency table by running this code

   `write.table(db,'my_data.txt',quote=FALSE,sep='\t', row.names=FALSE)`

   `file_path <- 'my_data.txt'`

   `dbtable <- read.delim(file_path, row.names=1)`
2. I created then a table containing only the columns I am interested in performing the Chi Square Test on, thus:

   `db2columns <- dbtable %>% select(B, C)`
3. I tried to run the Chi Square Test on db2columns, as it follows:
   `chisq <- chisq.test(db2columns) chisq`
   However it displays:
   `Error in chisq.test(db2columns) :  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite`
   I tried to convert db2columns to a contingency table but it doesn't work too, saying the same error.

I have then two questions

1. Is there a faster way to perform chi square test on two columns only without all the steps I wrote above?
2. How do I solve the error?

I am new to R so sorry if it's a simple question

Thank you!

Comment: You could do a `chisq.test(table(df$var1, df$var2))`. Also keep in mind that you use Yates correction if you don't mention `correct=False`. Also, what is the output of your table `db2columns`, it seems that you have 0 values which make the chi2 hypothesis quite hard to test.

Comment: @Yacine Hajji Hello! I tried using the code you wrote chisq.test(table(df$var1, df$var2)) but it says: Error in df$var2 : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. What is the problem? Do I have to write something else instead of "var1"? Also, I have 5000 rows on db2 columns and they both use 0 and 1. (example, patient 1: column A 0, column B 1; etc...). I don't really understand the problem with this.

Comment: Yes, instead of var1, you write your own variables. Instead of df, you write your own dataFrame :).
Could you add the output of dbcolumns in your question? Without this, it is tricky to know why there is an error.

Comment: Now your code works! I have no idea why. Just three more questions: 1) I noticed that your code works also without transforming my Excel into a contingency table, so I can directly use it on the imported Excel without all of the passages I made above. 2) Sorry for the stupid question, but where do I insert in the code "correct=False" in order to avoid Yates correction? Could you write the code with correct=False in it? 3) Why does your code work and the method I wrote above doesn't? I read it on a website. I continue in the next comment -

Comment: So normally when I create a contingency, as I read on the web, you put this code: dbtable <- read.delim(file_path, row.names=1) . But when I want to create the contingency of db2columns, it doesn't allow me to write "row.names=1" in the code so I only leave dbtable <- read.delim(file_path). Is maybe this the reason that the method above doesn't work? because maybe the chisquare considers also the first column with patients code, although it has numbers from 1 to 5000.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness and patient also!! :))

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @16631565 Thank you very much!! I didn't know about this and it is really helpful. I will do it next time

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Thank you very much!! I didn't know about this and it is really helpful. I will do it next time

Comment: Also does anyone get the notification when I write the comment? How do I tag someone?

Comment: @YacineHajjii sorry I didn't mention you before

Comment: Haha yeah I think if you tag people it notifies them. Dont think it notifies people for every comment but somebody can correct me if not.

Comment: This would be an example of db2columns: structure(list(red = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), blue = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: It seems that `db2bolumns` is not a `contingency table`. For a Chi2, you need a `contingency table` between your two variables of interest, i.e. `red` and `blue` variables. The function `table` in my example allows you to get a contingency table. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table